# Look-up Tables in oracle 10g

Tags: oracle10g

Hi All I am very new to oracle. I have a view having a where condition where brand in ('HP')
Now my report will run for HP Brand
But tomorrow if i want to run the report for different brand without modified the view or   report
So i think i need a create something like look up table
Please suggest the process how to create and how to pass the value to my view

Answer (score 0):

Remove the condition from your view, and apply it when selecting from the view:

```
SELECT x
  FROM your_view
 WHERE brand IN ('HP');
```

Tomorrow run

```
SELECT x
  FROM your_view
 WHERE brand IN ('X', 'Y', 'Z');
```

Answer (score 0):

I'll recomend you to move your brand condition from view level to report level. So your view will select all brands. But in place you use it in your report, you should add a list of brands:

```
select * from your_view
where brand in :brandList
```

But how to pass parameters depends on which tool you are using to create a report.